# How to programmatically use unix commands in Java to remove generated directories

Tags: java, unix, junit

I have a Java code that produces directories and files within them after execution. The directory names are like:

`ef3487f7457-43gfggf545-tgrg4536363-53345`

`ef3487f7457-43gfggf545-tgrg4536363-53462`

`ef3487f7457-43gfggf545-tgrg4536363-45742`

With files inside each directory.

How in java code can I delete these directories? I have no use for them and they are just increasing my diskspace usage. This is for a few unit tests I run before I check anything in.

Something like this:

```
@After
public void afterUnitTestExecution() {

    logger.info("Deleting bullshit files...");
    try {
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -r *-*");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code seems like it should work, but it does not. Manually executing `rm -r *-*` it works but doing it in Java (as shown above) does not. What is wrong? Any help or assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

Thanks for the suggestions guys. However I'd like not to use something specific to JUnit, I prefer to accomplish my goal using standard conventional Java not Junit

Comment: Can you use JUnit's TemporaryFolder? JUnit could handle this for you. https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/

Comment: So... You're using JUnit but you don't want to "use something specific to JUnit"? :-|

Comment: "I prefer to accomplish my goal using standard conventional Java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using JUNit TemporaryFolder

You should use junit rules designed to clean up files. JUnit comes with a [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) thats exactly designed for this kind of unit tests.

> The TemporaryFolder Rule allows creation of files and folders that
>   should be deleted when the test method finishes (whether it passes or
>   fails). Whether the deletion is successful or not is not checked by
>   this rule. No exception will be thrown in case the deletion fails.

It is easy to integrate it in your unit test:

```
public static class HasTempFolder {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
        File createdFolder= folder.newFolder("subfolder");
        // Run your code here
    }
}
```

### Using shell code

The reason your code isn't working, is because java isn't doing pattern expanding like the shell does, you can emulate this by starting a shell that executes your deletion:

```
new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "rm -r *-*").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

### Using pure java code to delete the directory

You can also use pure java code to delete the directory, use `File.listFiles()` to list the files in combination with a pattern matcher, then call `File.delete()` to delete the files.

**Java 1.8**

```
File f = new File("."); // Cuncurrent directory
Arrays.stream(f.listFiles(fi->fi.getName().match("[0-9a-f-]{36}"))).forEach(File::delete);
```

**Java 1.6 and higher**

```
File f = new File("."); // Cuncurrent directory
File[] files = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File fi) {
        return fi.getName().match("[0-9a-f-]{36}");
    }
});
for(File file : files) {
    file.delete();
}
```

The above code uses regex to find the files, then calls delete on them.

Comment: The directories I want to delete are created by an executable binary I run via wrapper code, I don't explicity create these directories, they are automatically generated from the executing binary. This doesn't seem like it'll work for me.

Comment: Run your whole test from the temporary directory then, with a processbuilder, you can change the directory of a external process that you execute

Comment: I must run it from root project directory, the binary won't work otherwise. Not sure why this is

Comment: I have added 2 alternative ways to the answer

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restircted to Java 1.6, do you know the Java7 equivalent of your code?